# Copy image file from web url to local folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web URL for the image. For example "http://testsite.com/web/abc.jpg". I want copy that URL in my local folder in "c:\images\"; and also when I copy that file into folder, I have to rename the image to "c:\images\xyz.jpg".

How can we do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Request the image, and save it. For example:

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  data = client.DownloadData("http://testsite.com/web/abc.jpg");
}
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\images\xyz.jpg", data);
```

Comment: I like this answer as opposed to directly using DownloadFile, as it gives an opportunity to compare the data before committing it to a file.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    wc.DownloadFile("http://testsite.com/web/abc.jpg", @"c:\images\xyz.jpg");
```

This assumes you actually have write rights to the `C:\images` folder.

Comment: Well try it with a URL that you are authorized to download from, otherwise you need to supply the WebClient with credentials that work on the target server.

Answer (score 3):

thats not too difficult. Open a WebCLient and grab the bits, save them locally....

```
using ( WebClient webClient = new WebClient() ) 
{
   using (Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(imgeUri))
   {
      using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream))
      {
         stream.Flush();
         stream.Close();
         bitmap.Save(saveto);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you force the jpg image into a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = "~/image/"; 
string picture = "Your picture name with extention";
path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), picture);
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                            {
wc.DownloadFile("http://testsite.com/web/abc.jpg", path);
                            }
```

Its works for me